# I cannot install 'pip' in Manjaro (Arch Linux): Error while retrieving files

Tags: python, linux, pip, archlinux, manjaro

I tried installing pip in [Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro) ([Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux)) from the terminal. I tried running the following command:

```
sudo pacman -S python-pip
```

It gave me the following error:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d69ok.png)

```
 python-pip-22.3-1-any.pkg.tar.zst failed to download
 Total (1/7)                                                                                                        3.9 MiB  80.0 KiB/s 00:50 [#######################################################################################] 100%
error: failed retrieving file 'python-pip-22.3-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.ustc.edu.cn : SSL connection timeout
error: failed retrieving file 'python-pip-22.3-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'python-pip-22.3-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.tarnkappe.info : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'python-pip-22.3-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirrors.ucr.ac.cr : SSL connection timeout
error: failed retrieving file 'python-pip-22.3-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from manjaro.ipacct.com : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed retrieving file 'python-pip-22.3-1-any.pkg.tar.zst' from mirror.alpix.eu : The requested URL returned error: 404
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (failed to retrieve some files)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

How can I fix this issue? And why wasn't pip packaged with Python in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: just run `pacman -Syu python-pip` instead of `pacman -S python-pip`

As Arch Linux (and Manjaro) are rolling releases, it is not recommended to do [partial updates](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/system_maintenance#Avoid_certain_pacman_commands) as they can break packages or in this case after some time, the Pacman database can be outdated, so you should **always** do an update in order to prevent any issues when installing/updating packages. Unless you know explicitly that you do not want to do a partial update, you should not do it.

As for the 404 error, it is pretty common that the mirrors of the packages delete the old packages for those reasons.

In the case for `pip`, it is unknown to me, but it should be that `python` and `pip` are not the same and should be treated as such.

Comment: That is a very good tip! It was crucial for installing [QMK](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/faq_general?id=what-is-qmk) under [ArcoLinux](https://arcolinux.info/) (also Arch Linux derived). The QMK official documentation says `sudo pacman --needed --noconfirm -S git python-pip libffi` whereas `sudo pacman --needed --noconfirm -Syu git python-pip libffi` got it past the failing installation of pip (`/usr/bin/python: No module named pip`). That is, `-Syu` instead of `-S`.